# How can I get a weather display to use the previous data if the internet dies and no update?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, display

I've got a weather display for a Pi which uses pygame to display the data
The issue I have is when the internet dies for any reason there is no update and the display shows blank data
What I'd like to do is if there is no update then it keeps the previous data on the screen
is this possible?

This is an example of the code that displays the data

```
    if forecastData.status == forecast.STATUS_OK: 
    ren = font.render("Solar Radiation: {} W/m2".format(forecastData.solar_radiation), 1, pg.Color('black'), pg.Color(185,208,240))
else:
    ren = font.render("Solar Radiation: ", 1, pg.Color('black'), pg.Color(185,208,240))  
screen.blit(ren, (5*HRES//1600, 430*VRES//900-ren.get_height()//2))
```

When there is no update this displays Solar Radiation: only  - I'd like this to use the previous data  - ie DONT update this section of the display

Comment: why dont you use the exact same concept of status checking with weather data too?

Comment: Because I don't know how
I'm really new to Python and I did try but it doesn't work

I cannot figure out how to get the forecast module to not return anything if the url does not resolve

In the json decode section of the forecast module I have
        except (socket.timeout, socket.gaierror, urllib.error.URLError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError, KeyError):
            logging.warning("Error retrieving forecast data")

This stops the program crashing but it still sends blank data to the display module

Comment: how about when excepting that error You also send the current data?

Comment: can you post the part of the code that is responsible for weather data?

Comment: Are you able to create a [mcve] so it's possible to help you with your specific problem? It looks like you need to only update the `ForecastData` object in your `Forecast` instance when the data has been successfully retrieved.

Comment: If you want to use a named color for your font background, `lightsteelblue2` is closest to `(185, 208, 240)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you should do is check the status before updating `self.data` in your `Forecast` class:

```
#Now make it available to outside world.
if data.status == STATUS_OK:
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.data = data
    self.lock.release()
```

Can't be sure as it's not possible to run any of your code samples.

Here is a minimal example that uses a thread to simulate data retrieval with the occasional error.

```
import random
import threading
import time
import pygame

class ForecastThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()  # starts on instantiation!

    def retrieve_data(self):
        global data
        # make request to forecast service and parse response
        response = random.randint(1, 5)
        if response == 1:
            # Request failed
            data = """(○o◌!*^#@!@"""
        else:  # success
            data = random.choice(("Cloudy", "Rainy", "Stormy", "Sunny", "Windy"))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not running:  # exit thread if main loop exits
                return
            else:
                self.retrieve_data()
                time.sleep(1)  # sleep for a second

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 240
FPS = 30

random.seed(98765432)
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# grab the first installed font
sys_font = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_fonts()[0], 100)
data = ""  # create globals before thread
running = True
forecaster_thread = ForecastThread()  # note: thread is auto-starting
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
    # update title bar
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"Forecaster FPS: {clock.get_fps():.1f}")
    # fill background to clear
    window.fill(pygame.Color("lightsteelblue2"))
    # create image
    image = sys_font.render(data, True, pygame.Color("black"))
    window.blit(image, (50, 50))  # blit close to centre
    # show surface
    pygame.display.update()
    # limit frames
    clock.tick(FPS)
pygame.quit()
```

Running this code will initially display Cloudy then change to the gibberish data indicating a failed request.

If you change the `retrieve_data()` function to not update `data` on failure, then no gibberish will be displayed.

```
def retrieve_data(self):
    global data
    # make request to forecast service and parse response
    response = random.randint(1, 5)
    if response == 1:
        # Request failed
        print("Failed Request")  # log the error
    else:  # success
        data = random.choice(("Cloudy", "Rainy", "Stormy", "Sunny", "Windy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

"import random" I have tried your solution so many ways but it always fails Does this help?... this is the full code to collect the forecast

```
import json
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import pdb
import threading
import pygame as pg
import logging
import os.path
import socket

FORECAST_URL = "https://swd.weatherflow.com/swd/rest/better_forecast?api_key=20c70eae-e62f-4d3b-b3a4-8586e90f3ac8&station_id=44303&lat=53.440&lon=-2.105"

TIMEOUT = 15
STATUS_TIMEOUT = "Timeout"
STATUS_OK = "OK"

def nullis0hook(d):
    """This is a hook for the JSON decoder, replacing null with 0."""
    for k in d.keys():
        if d[k]==None:
            d[k]=0
    return d

class ForecastData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = STATUS_OK
        self.conditions=""
        self.iconnow = ""
        self.updateTime="946684800"     
        self.tempnow=0
        self.templow=30
        self.temphigh=-10
        self.sea_level_pressure=0
        self.station_pressure=0
        self.pressure_trend=""
        self.relative_humidity=0
        self.wind_avg=0
        self.wind_direction_cardinal=""
        self.angle=0
        self.wind_gust=0
        self.solar_radiation=0
        self.uv=0
        self.feels_like=0
        self.dew_point=0
        self.wet_bulb_temperature="" 
        self.delta_t=0
        self.air_density=0
        self.lightning_strike_last_distance="0"
        self.lightning1=""
        self.lightning_strike_last_epoch="946684800"
        self.precip_accum_local_yesterday="0"
        self.precip_accum_local_day="0"
        self.condday=[""]*6
        self.icon=[""]*6
        self.iconday_filename = [os.path.join("images",os.path.join("forecast_icons","--_"))]*6
        self.iconday = [pg.image.load(os.path.join("images",os.path.join("forecast_icons","--_1.bmp"))).convert()]*6
        self.thighday=[0]*6
        self.tlowday=[0]*6
        self.sunriseday=[""]*6        
        self.sunsetday=[""]*6          
        self.precprday=[0]*6
        self.precpiconday=[""]*6
        self.preciptypeday=[""]*6
        self.conditionshour=[""]*9
        self.iconhour=[""]*9
        self.precipprhour=[""]*9
        self.preciptypehour=[""]*9
        self.feelslikehour=[0]*9
        self.conditionshour=[""]*9
        self.iconhour=[""]*9
        self.precipprhour=[""]*9
        self.preciptypehour=[""]*9
        self.feelslikehour=[0]*9
        self.airtemphour=[0]*9
        self.windavghour=[0]*9        
        self.forecast_icon_filename = os.path.join("images",os.path.join("weather_icons","--_.bmp"))
        self.forecast_icon = pg.image.load(self.forecast_icon_filename).convert()
        self.kia = pg.image.load(os.path.join("images",os.path.join("weather_icons","kia.png"))).convert()
   

#The Forecast class retrieves the weatherflow.com forecast and extracts relevant forecast data. 
#Note: pygame display must be initialized before constructing a Forecast object

class ForeCastHour:
  def __init__(self):
      self.conditions = [""]*6
      self.icon = ["--_"]*6
      self.precipr = [""]*6
      self.precip_type = [""]*6
      self.feels_like = [""]*6


class Forecast:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ForecastData()
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.max_wind_gust=0
        self.templow=30
        self.temphigh=-10    
        self.updateTime = ""


    def getData(self):
        """Get most recently retrieved consistent set of data."""
        self.lock.acquire()
        data = self.data
        self.lock.release()
        return data

    def midnightReset(self):
        """Reset any values that require resetting at midnight"""
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.data.wind_gust=0
        self.lock.release()

    def update(self):
        """Update the forecast data"""
        data = ForecastData()       
        try:
            req = urllib.request.Request(FORECAST_URL)            
            with urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=TIMEOUT) as response:
                raw = response.read()             
                forecast_json = json.loads(raw, object_hook=nullis0hook)
                data.status = STATUS_OK
                self.updateTime = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["time"]
                data.updateTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(self.updateTime))
                data.conditions = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["conditions"]               
                iconnow = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["icon"]
                
                if iconnow == "null":               
                    iconnow = "--_" #icon replacement  
                if iconnow == "":               
                    iconnow = "--_" #icon replacement  
                data.iconnow_filename = os.path.join("images",os.path.join("weather_icons",iconnow+".bmp"))
                if os.path.exists(data.iconnow_filename):
                    data.iconnow = pg.image.load(data.iconnow_filename).convert()
                else:
                    logging.warning("Weather icon file {} not found.".format(data.iconnow_filename))
                data.tempnow = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["air_temperature"] 
                if data.tempnow < self.templow:
                    self.templow = data.tempnow
                if data.tempnow > self.temphigh:
                    self.temphigh = data.tempnow
                data.templow = self.templow
                data.temphigh = self.temphigh            
                
                data.sea_level_pressure = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["sea_level_pressure"]
                data.station_pressure = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["station_pressure"]
                data.pressure_trend = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["pressure_trend"]
                data.relative_humidity = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["relative_humidity"]
                data.wind_avg = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["wind_avg"]* 2.23694 #Convert mps to mph
                data.wind_gust = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["wind_gust"] * 2.23694 #Convert mps to mph                       
                data.angle = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["wind_direction"]
                if data.angle <= 180:
                    data.angle = data.angle + 180
                else:
                    data.angle = data.angle - 180                
                data.wind_direction_cardinal = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["wind_direction_cardinal"]                     
                data.solar_radiation = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["solar_radiation"]
                data.uv = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["uv"]
                data.feels_like = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["feels_like"]
                lightning_strike_last_distance = forecast_json["current_conditions"].get("lightning_strike_last_distance", 0)                   
                lightning1 = lightning_strike_last_distance*0.621371 #Convert kph to mph     
                data.lightning_strike_last_distance = "{0:.1f} miles away ".format(lightning1)
                lightning_strike_last_epoch = forecast_json["current_conditions"].get("lightning_strike_last_epoch")
                data.lightning_strike_last_epoch = time.strftime("%d %b", time.localtime(lightning_strike_last_epoch))                            
                data.precip_accum_local_yesterday = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["precip_accum_local_yesterday"]
                data.precip_accum_local_day = forecast_json["current_conditions"]["precip_accum_local_day"]

                
                for day in range(6):
                    data.sunriseday[day] = forecast_json["forecast"]["daily"][day]["sunrise"]
                    data.sunriseday[day] = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(data.sunriseday[day]))
                    data.sunsetday[day] = forecast_json["forecast"]["daily"][day]["sunset"]
                    data.sunsetday[day] = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(data.sunsetday[day]))
                    data.condday[day] = forecast_json["forecast"]["daily"][day]["conditions"]
                    icon = forecast_json["forecast"]["daily"][day]["icon"]
                    data.iconday_filename[day] = os.path.join("images",os.path.join("forecast_icons",icon+"1.bmp"))
                    if os.path.exists(data.iconday_filename[day]):
                        iconimage = pg.image.load(data.iconday_filename[day]).convert()
                        data.iconday[day] = iconimage
                    else:
                        logging.warning("Forecast icon file {} not found.".format(data.iconday_filename[day]))                   
                    data.thighday[day] = forecast_json["forecast"]["daily"][day]["air_temp_high"]
                    data.tlowday[day] = forecast_json["forecast"]["daily"][day]["air_temp_low"]
                    data.precprday[day] = forecast_json["forecast"]["daily"][day]["precip_probability"]
                    if data.precprday[day] != 0:
                        data.precpiconday[day] = forecast_json["forecast"]["daily"][day]["precip_icon"]
                        data.preciptypeday[day] = forecast_json["forecast"]["daily"][day]["precip_type"]
                        
                data.forecast_icon_filename = os.path.join("images",os.path.join("weather_icons",iconnow+".bmp"))
                if os.path.exists(data.forecast_icon_filename):
                    data.forecast_icon = pg.image.load(data.forecast_icon_filename).convert()
                else:
                    logging.warning("Forecast icon file {} not found.".format(data.forecast_icon_filename))

                for hours in range(9):                
                    ps = forecast_json["forecast"]["hourly"][hours]["conditions"]                  
                    if ps == "Wintry Mix Possible":
                        ps = "Winty-P" 
                    if ps ==  "Wintry Mix Likely":
                        ps = "Winty-L"      
                    if ps ==  "Rain Likely":
                        ps = "Rain-L" 
                    if ps ==  "Rain Possible":
                        ps ="Rain-P"  
                    if ps ==  "Snow Possible":
                        ps = "Snow-P"   
                    if ps ==  "Thunderstorms Likely":
                        ps = "ThundrL"          
                    if ps ==  "Thunderstorms Possible":
                        ps = "ThundrP"   
                    if ps ==  "Partly Cloudy":
                        ps = "Clouds"   
                    if ps == "Very Light Rain":
                        ps = "drizzle"
                    data.conditionshour[hours] = "{}".format(ps)                   
                    data.iconhour[hours] = forecast_json["forecast"]["hourly"][hours]["icon"]
                    pp = forecast_json["forecast"]["hourly"][hours]["precip_probability"]
                    data.precipprhour[hours] = "{}%".format(pp)
                    if pp == 0:
                        data.preciptypehour[hours] = "0"
                    else:
                        data.preciptypehour[hours] = forecast_json["forecast"]["hourly"][hours]["precip_type"]
                    data.feelslikehour[hours] = "{} C".format(forecast_json["forecast"]["hourly"][hours]["feels_like"])
                    data.airtemphour[hours] = forecast_json["forecast"]["hourly"][hours]["air_temperature"]
                    data.windavghour[hours] = forecast_json["forecast"]["hourly"][hours]["wind_avg"]*0.621371 #Convert kph to mph

                #datetime object containing current date and time
                now = datetime.now()
                data.updateTime = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                self.updateTime = now
         
            
            
        except (socket.timeout, socket.gaierror, urllib.error.URLError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError, KeyError):
            logging.warning("Error retrieving forecast data")
            #declare timeout only after timeout period
            if datetime.now() - self.updateTime > timedelta(seconds=TIMEOUT):
                data.status = STATUS_TIMEOUT
                data.updateTime = self.data.updateTime #Use old update time value
            else: #If timeout period has not elapsed yet, use previous data
                logging.info("Not timing out yet")
                self.data = self.data   #Use old value                            
            if datetime.now() - self.updateTime > timedelta(seconds=TIMEOUT):
                data.status = STATUS_TIMEOUT
            else: #If timeout period has not elapsed yet, use previous data
                logging.info("Not timing out yet")
                data = self.data

        #Now make it available to outside world.
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.data = data
        self.lock.release()
```

And this is what works when there is internet, but when the internet goes off it doesn't use the old data

```
    '''THIS IS THE FORECAST SECTION THAT WORKS WHEN THERE IS INTENET AND FORECAST UPDATES
BUT WHEN THERE IS NO UPDATE IT JUST DISPLAYS THE TEXT AND DOES NOT USE THE OLD DATA VALUE'''


if forecastData.status == forecast.STATUS_OK:
    ren = font.render("battery voltage : " + "{} V".format(forecastData.battery), 1, pg.Color('white'), pg.Color(162, 160, 160))
else:
    ren = font.render("", 1, pg.Color('white'), pg.Color(162, 160, 160))           
screen.blit(ren, (700*HRES//1600, VRES//60)) 

if forecastData.status == forecast.STATUS_OK:    
    ren = font.render("Conditions:         {}       ".format(forecastData.conditions), 1, pg.Color('black'), pg.Color(185,208,240))
else:
    ren = font.render("Conditions: ", 1, pg.Color('black'), pg.Color(185,208,240))
screen.blit(ren, (5*HRES//1600, 70*VRES//900-ren.get_height()//2))   


'''THIS IS THE ERROR MESSAGE I GET LOGGED'''
2021-04-15 13:28:41,057 - root - INFO - Updating forecast.
2021-04-15 13:28:41,087 - root - WARNING - Error retrieving forecast data
2021-04-15 13:29:11,049 - root - WARNING - Previous every-minute thread still running. Not relaunching.
2021-04-15 13:29:26,602 - root - INFO - t key pressed. Toggle fullscreen.
2021-04-15 13:29:41,085 - root - WARNING - Previous every-minute thread still running. Not relaunching.
2021-04-15 13:30:11,089 - root - WARNING - Previous every-minute thread still running. Not relaunching.

'''THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT THE ERROR REFERS TO'''

def everyMinuteThreadFunction():
    """This thread function executes once every minute."""
    global initialWeatherUpdateReceived, everyMinuteThreadRunning
    everyMinuteThreadRunning = True
    assert(forecastObj)
    checkMidnightRollOver()
    logging.info("Updating forecast.")
    forecastObj.update()
    forecastData = forecastObj.getData()
 
    if forecastData.status == forecast.STATUS_OK:
        logging.info("Forecast data: {}".format(vars(forecastData)))          
    #The first time we pass here is a good time to kick off the five minute task. We now have our first
    #forecast evice data available
    if not initialWeatherUpdateReceived:
        #program a periodic timer used to kick off the everyFiveMinutesThreadFunction.
        pg.time.set_timer(EVERY_FIVE_MINUTES_THREAD_FUNCTION_EVENT, 5*60000)
        
        #Kick off the task now, for the initial interval.
        t = threading.Thread(target=everyFiveMinutesThreadFunction, args=())
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        updateGauge()

    initialWeatherUpdateReceived = True
    everyMinuteThreadRunning = False
```